# Como encontrar coordenadas no maps da Apple?

Tags: objective-c, coordenadas, maps, mapkit

Preciso mostrar diversos lugares diferentes no mapa, um para cada local, gostaria de saber como posso apontar para cada coordenada através do código?

No caso o app é para iOS, usando Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando o `MapKit` são necessárias poucas linhas de código. Depois de adicionado o framework no projeto e o mapa em si na tela, você pode inserir um ponto em determinada coordenada desta maneira:

```
// Alloca um novo MKPointAnnotation que pode ser usado como pin no mapa
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

// Ajusta para a coornedada desejada
point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-21.805149, -49.089977);

// Pode customizar o título e subtitulo
point.title = @"Título";
point.subtitle = @"Subtitulo do pin";

// Adiciona o pin no mapa
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
```

Comment: Cara sua resposta é fenomenal!!! Me adiantou 90% do trab. Mas sao mais de 20 localizacoes e o cliente é de outro estado e ele não sabe como fazer isso. Eu pensei em ver as coordenadas no Goole Maps e converter para o mapa da Apple, vou dar mais uma pesquisda! Mas sua resposta é realmente util! Obrigado novamente!!!

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui tbm, parece que as coordenadas do Google Maps tbm serve para o MapKit, mas não é 100% preciso :/